# SQL get records having latest association matching a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

## Context

Using PostgreSQL, I'm storing `articles` and their associated `events`. Here is a simple structure of the 2 tables for the sake of the example:

**Articles table**

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
| ID |   title   |      description      |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | article 1 | article 1 description |
|  2 | article 2 | article 2 description |
|  3 | article 3 | article 3 description |
|  4 | article 4 | article 4 description |
|  5 | article 5 | article 5 description |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+
```

**Events table**

```
+-----+-----------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| ID  |   name    | eventable_id | eventable_type | created_at   |
+-----+-----------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|  1  | validated |            1 | Article        | 2020-05-10   |
|  2  | reported  |            1 | Article        | 2020-05-11   |
|  3  | reported  |            2 | Article        | 2020-05-10   |
|  4  | reported  |            2 | Article        | 2020-05-11   |
|  5  | reported  |            2 | Article        | 2020-05-12   |
|  6  | reported  |            3 | Article        | 2020-05-20   |
|  7  | validated |            3 | Article        | 2020-05-21   |
|  8  | reported  |            4 | Article        | 2020-05-12   |
|  9  | moved     |            4 | Article        | 2020-05-13   |
|  10 | reported  |            4 | Article        | 2020-05-14   |
|  11 | moved     |            5 | Article        | 2020-05-13   |
|  12 | moved     |            5 | Article        | 2020-05-14   |
+-----+-----------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

## Problem

Here I need to be able to get all `articles` which have their latest `events` being `reported`.

So for example, following the data above, we must only get:

- `article 1`: because it has been `validated` then `reported`
- `article 2`: because it only has been `reported`
- `article 4`: because it has been `moved` then `reported` (same as article 1)

As you can see:

- `article 3`: should not be return because its latest event is `validated`.
- `article 5`: should not be return because its latest event is `moved`.

I can easily find all `articles` having a `reported` event. But how to get the ones having their latest event to be `reported` ?

Here is what I did try to do so far without success:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE name = 'reported'
    ORDER BY created_at
    LIMIT 1
) AS e ON e.moderable_id = a.id AND e.moderable_type = 'Article'
```

We currently have:

- 459 892 `articles`
- 62 074 `events`

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Note: you seem to have fewer events than articles?

Comment: @wildplasser yes because not all articles has an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select a.*
from articles a
where 
    (
        select e.name
        from events e
        where e.eventable_id = a.id and e.eventable_type = 'Article'
        order by created_at desc 
        limit 1
    ) = 'reported'
```

We could also express this with a lateral join:

```
select a.*
from articles a
inner join lateral (
    select e.name 
    from events 
    where e.eventable_id = a.id and e.eventable_type = 'Article'
    order by created_at desc 
    limit 1
)  x on x.status = 'reported'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both of your example are actually working (I need to run more test with bigger data to ensure that). I have a question: which of these query will be the fastest ? We currently have 459 891 `articles` and 62 074 `events`

Comment: @lkartono: there are pretty much equivalent I think (and possibly, they produce the same execution plan). Still, you might want to assess the performance against your data. An index on `events(eventable_id, eventable_type, created_at, name)` may help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip related to the index, went from 21 seconds to 118 ms :)